# How to view metadata of local/downloaded .deb files in Debian

Tags: debian

While one can download a .deb package using `apt download $package.deb` there doesn't seem to be any way to see the metadata of that file. I mean by metadata something like -

```
[$] aptitude show dgit                                                                                                             
Package: dgit                            
Version: 3.10
State: not installed
Priority: optional
Section: devel
Maintainer: Ian Jackson <ijackson@chiark.greenend.org.uk>
Architecture: all
Uncompressed Size: 309 k
Depends: perl, libwww-perl, libdpkg-perl, git-core, devscripts, dpkg-dev, git-buildpackage, liblist-moreutils-perl, coreutils (>= 8.23-1~) | realpath, libdigest-sha-perl, dput, curl, apt, libjson-perl, ca-certificates, libtext-iconv-perl, libtext-glob-perl
Recommends: ssh-client
Suggests: sbuild
Description: git interoperability with the Debian archive
 dgit (with the associated infrastructure) makes it possible to treat the Debian archive as a git repository. 

 dgit push constructs uploads from git commits 

 dgit clone and dgit fetch construct git commits from uploads.
```

Hopefully there is a way to view the depends, recommends etc.

I had viewed also using less in various forums to do the same thing but couldn't get it to work as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`dpkg-deb`, which is part of `dpkg` and therefore always available, can show all the control information for a binary package using only its `.deb` file:

```
$ dpkg-deb -I joystick_1.6.0-2_amd64.deb
 new debian package, version 2.0.
 size 49454 bytes: control archive=1509 bytes.
     892 bytes,    24 lines      control              
    1887 bytes,    30 lines      md5sums              
 Package: joystick
 Version: 1:1.6.0-2
 Architecture: amd64
 Maintainer: Stephen Kitt <skitt@debian.org>
 Installed-Size: 176
 Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15), libsdl1.2debian (>= 1.2.11)
 Recommends: evtest, inputattach
 Breaks: stella (<< 4.7.2)
 Replaces: stella (<< 4.7.2)
 Section: utils
 Priority: extra
 Homepage: https://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxconsole/
 Description: set of testing and calibration tools for joysticks
  Some useful tools for using joysticks:
   evdev-joystick(1) - joystick calibration tool
   ffcfstress(1)     - force-feedback stress test
   ffmvforce(1)      - force-feedback orientation test
   ffset(1)          - force-feedback configuration tool
   fftest(1)         - general force-feedback test
   jstest(1)         - joystick test
   jscal(1)          - joystick calibration tool
  .
  evtest and inputattach, which used to be part of this package, are now
  available separately.
```

There are quite a few different options to select the content to display, from the package’s file listing to specific (binary) control files; see [`man dpkg-deb`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/dpkg/dpkg-deb.1.en.html) for details.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way of seeing the metadata of a Debian binary package is by using `less` (to be precise, the `less` preprocessor) on the binary package. In other words:

```
less pkgname...deb
```

Here is the relevant content of `/bin/lesspipe`.

```
            *.deb|*.udeb|*.ddebi|*.ipk)
                        echo "$1:"; dpkg --info "$1"
                        echo
                        echo '*** Contents:'; dpkg-deb --contents "$1"
                            ;;
```

To make this work, you need to add the following somewhere where it will be sourced. `~/.bashrc` is a good place.

```
export LESSOPEN="|/usr/bin/lesspipe %s"
```